# Control the selection range in Word document from Javascript Add-in

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-addins, word-addins

Given some range in the Word Document body text, I want to set the current selection to that range and replace the text within.

Does anyone know how I can control the current selection within a Word document from an add-in using the Javascript API? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview

I understand I can get the current selection within a document using `context.document.getSelection()`, but how do I get any selection within a document or specify what part of the document is selected? How do I programmatically control what is selected in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the selected range of **user selection** :

```
  // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
        Word.run(function (context) {

            var range = context.document.getSelection(); // Create a range proxy object for the current selection.
            context.load(range);
            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync().then(function () {

                if (range.isEmpty) //Check if the selection is empty
                {
                    return;
                }
                var html = range.getHtml();
                return context.sync().then(function () {

                    var htmlVal = html.value; //Get the selected text in HTML 
               });
             });
           });
```

To set in the selected range **of user**:

```
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var range = context.document.getSelection();// Create a range proxy object for the current selection.

       range.clear();                                                             
       range.delete();

      // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
       return context.sync().then(function () {

         range.styleBuiltIn = "Normal";                                                               
         range.insertText("your text"); // Queue a command to insert the encrypted text instead the current text 
      });
   })
```

So if you have somehow already the  'range' you don't need to get it.

** If you don't want to take user selection and want to change just some part on document you could achieve it with paragraph selection , you could find more information about paragraph object and what you could do with this here:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph

good luck

Comment: Thanks @OriEng. This isn't quite what I was getting at, sorry. I'll try to clarify my question. I understand I can get the current selection within a document, but how do I get any selection with a document? Something like `new Word.Range(start, end)`, where `start` and `end` are any indices within the document text.

Comment: @CraigSketchley What you mean by 'anyselection' ? sorry I still not understand your question

Comment: No worries @OriEng. Sorry I wasn't any clearer. To put it simply, I want to programmatically control the selection. From what I understand, I can only access what the user has selected, but how does my add-in select any part of the document?

Comment: @CraigSketchley I think your option could be a paragraph selection and then replace this paragraph : https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph 
Another options is just select all , I don't find on API another alternative to choose selection

Comment: Thanks @OriEng, I couldn't find any API that allowed me to programmatically control the selection either. Thanks for the suggestions though. If you want to update your answer to include the paragraph API method, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @CraigSketchley Happy to help and I hope you success to solve your problem . I update my answer,  tell me if to add to there something else that necessary.